# Most efficient way to remove rows in pandas df based on condition of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

We have a text extraction model and want to balance the data so that the label counts are more equal. Here is some dummy data of the label and it's counts.

```
{'shoe': 5, 'shirt': 2, 'short': 5}
```

The data frame looks like this.

```
                                       sample_object   shoe  shirt  short
0  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...   True   True   True
1  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...   True  False   True
2  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...   True  False   True
3  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...   True  False  False
4  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...  False  False   True
5  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...  False   True   True
6  <ml_development.text_extraction.models.data.Sa...   True  False  False
```

Basically a sample object contains information about the labels, the text, etc. for training a model. In the following columns there is stated if a sample contains an example for a shoe, shirt, short or not.

So this is what needs to be done. We give a max_n to balance out our labels. So if we had a max_n of 3, rows [1, 2] could be removed. Another even better possibility are rows [1, 3, 4]. This is because we want randomization and in this way we remove a sample that has a shoe and short, a sample that only has a shoe and a sample that only has a short.

We don't want to remove row 0 for example unless we absolutely have to. This is because then we also lose an example of shirt while we originally didn't have to remove any for this label. Of course the possibility exist that we do need to do this.

Let's say we only need to remove 1 shirt. Well, than we'll remove row 5 since this removes the least of other labels that don't need to be removed. If we would remove the other possibility for a shirt (row 0) then a shoe and a short gets removed as well instead of only a short.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have `n` samples and `m` labels. For each label `j`, you have `n_j` samples containing an example of that label.
Let's denote `L[i, j]` the truth-value of the proposition "sample `i` contains label `j`", for all `i, j` in `[0:n-1] × [0:m-1]`.

Then `n_j = Σ_i L[i, j]`. And the matrix `L` has dimensions `(n × m)`

Consider the vector `X`of size `(1 × n)` that contains a probability to include sample `i` as element `X[i]`.

Finally let `B` denote the vector of size `(1 × m)` that contains the number of samples you want for each label, in element `B[j]`.

Then you can use linear algebra to solve for `X` in `X . L = B`.

Assuming `n > m`, this will have many solutions for `X`. You can decide any method you like to pick one, or use multiple solutions to run your training multiple times and test the effect of discarding part of the data.

Once you have picked a solution for `X`, transform it into a probability `P[i] = X[i] / S`. where `S` is a number you have to choose to ensure that probabilities are within [0:1]. Then, select each sample with probability `P[i]`.

`E[j]`, the expected number of samples for a given label `j` is then given by

`E[j] = sum(P[i] * L[i, j], for i in range(n)) = B[j] / S`

`S` is independent of `j`, so the number of samples you will get this way will be proportional to `B[j]`.